# Why does express not properly handle routes of the form "/first/second"?

Tags: node.js, express

It seems that routes which are of the the form '/first' are handled properly.

But if routes of the form '/first/second' are defined, then there are errors.

For example, if both pages contain

```
<link href="css/dashboard.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Then in the first case, the link is requested correctly (as `css/dashboard.css`)

But in the second case:

The url requested is `/first/css/dashboard.css`, which will obviously result in a 404.

This makes no sense and seems to be some kind of bug. Can someone confirm this, or is this expected behaviour ?

Comment: Is it about routes or static files ?

Comment: @TGrif The problem seems to occur when trying to access static files like css and js